# Object of class Collection could not be converted to int [LARAVEL]

Tags: database, laravel, int

```
\DB::table('orders')->where('id', $orderid)->update(['price' => \DB::raw('price' - $price)]);
```

the price column at the DB is decimal, and when I try to subtract a value on the database, i get this error saying that it could not be converted to int

Comment: what is `$price` can u post it's declaration and assignment

Comment: $price= \DB::table('order_products')->where('id', $orderid_prod)->pluck('price');

Comment: `$preco = \DB::table('pedido_produtos')->where('id', $pedidoid_prod)->pluck('preco'); ` is most likely giving you back an array or object. Run a `dd($preco)` and see what you are getting. If it is an array or object, just pull the value out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `dd($price)` u will see that it is collection. `pluck()` returns the array of all values. So, use $price[0] instead of `$price`

Or you can change the price assignment as bellow

```
$price= \DB::table('order_products')->where('id', $orderid_prod)->first()->price;
```